# Is there a way to monitor Microsoft Teams data at NewRelic?

Tags: api, office365, integration, microsoft-teams, newrelic

I am new to New Relic & have been trying to find how to monitor Microsoft Teams data at New Relic. 
For example,

1. No. of users,
2. No. of calls attended,
3. Audio & video quality metrices

Any help on how to integrate/configure MS Teams at New Relic would be appreciated.

Comment: Just need to confirm, Are you looking for API to get the participants in Teams meeting and their data?

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Yes some doc which explains how to integrate with New Relic

Comment: This is in the works w M365 reporting Graph APIs. This will land in CY Q3 in GA